# No time for idle chat (i.e. missing timestamp for chat notification)

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, timestamps

One of the notifications in my inbox appears without a timestamp:

[image: no timestamp in chat notifications]

It never happened before, neither with the old inbox, nor with the new inbox. This is ordinary chat reply notification, can't see anything out of the ordinary with the message or notification that might explain the missing timestamp.

The timestamp does appear in the global inbox on se.com though:

[image: inbox item with timestamp in the network profile inbox]

I've tried marking the item as read/unread, clicking it, reloading, clearing cache, citing a "Bring Timestamp Back" spell, to no avail.

Can I have the timestamp back, please?

Comment: hm, why one and not the other?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that's a good question..