# In the inbox, "N hours ago" is underneath the envelope icon when there's a URL in the notification

Tags: bug, design, notifications

In this image, see how both messages were posted 9 hours ago but in the first one that text is covered by the envelope icon:

[image: 9 hours envelope]

It still happens when the message is read. I think it's because of the link, since the other message is able to wrap much earlier in the line.

Browser: iOS Chrome

Comment: Well it's because the long word without breaks, pretty sure a comment can trigger this bug as well. (i.e. long comment without a space.)

Comment: Was going to close as dupe of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385600/no-time-for-idle-chat-i-e-missing-timestamp-for-chat-notification) but it's bit different (in your case, the timestamp is visible) so leaving open for now, might be related but different bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry It might be a dupe, if the timestamp in yours isn't actually gone but rather just pushed so far off to the right that it's covered up.

Comment: Yeah, it is pushed. Didn't take screenshot or edited the report, but later I inspected the HTML and it's there. It doesn't really matter as it's technical detail the developer can easily see if/when going to fix, the end result is the same, no timestamp is showing up.